# Debugging Canvas/WEBGL game's low framerate on a fast PC

Tags: javascript, profiling, frame-rate

Some people running my game on their phones/tablets/laptops say they get 5-15fps sometimes, but having a pretty decent PC the game never drops below 60 on mine so I don't know how to go about investigating the issue if I have no way to replicate it on my end. The CPU throttling in Chrome only goes up to x6 and doesn't seem to affect it much at all, I imagine because it's mainly the GPU doing all the work?

Is there a *good* way of going about investigating these FPS drops on my PC without trying to hunt down some old phone for remote debugging?